# Weird random periods/dot in my responsive timeline

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So I copied this responsive timeline from codepen because I am lazy to create an entire responsive timeline. I modifed it to what I need for my website. Although there is just one very annoying minor problem that I want to get rid of and that is there is this period on the left column in the last line of the paragraph which is "floating" on the left side of the last line. *See screenshot*

Is this something to do with CSS? You may run the code snippet to see it for yourself.

I would like to get rid of this annoying minor problem so that way it doesn't confuse the readers when they are reading my website.

It is indeed a period. *See second screenshot*

[image]

[image]

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: #F1F2F6;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #777
}

h1 span {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #CCD1D9;
  z-index: 1
}

.timeline-block {
  width: -webkit-calc(50% + 8px);
  width: -moz-calc(50% + 8px);
  width: calc(50% + 8px);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  clear: both;
}

.timeline-block-right {
  float: right;
}

.timeline-block-left {
  float: left;
  direction: rtl
}

.marker {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #F5F7FA;
  background: #4FC1E9;
  margin-top: 10px;
  z-index: 9999
}

.timeline-content {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: #666
}

.timeline-content h3 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500
}

.timeline-content span {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #a4a4a4;
}

.timeline-content p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  color: #888;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container:before {
    left: 8px;
    width: 2px;
  }
  .timeline-block {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .timeline-block-right {
    float: none;
  }
  .timeline-block-left {
    float: none;
    direction: ltr;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Pure Css responsive <span>timeline</span></h1>

<div class="container">

  <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h3>First Year</h3>
      <span>Some work experience</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-left">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h3>Seconed Year</h3>
      <span>Some work experience</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h3>Third Year</h3>
      <span>Some work experience</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-left">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h3>Fourth Year</h3>
      <span>Some work experience</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h3>Fifth Year</h3>
      <span>Some work experience</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take off the "direction: rtl;" from timeline-block-left class. and insert "text-align:justify" Like this:

```
.timeline-block-left {
  float: left;
  text-align:justify;
}
```

Comment: Hey that worked man! Thanks! Just one simple line to fix the problem  and it is gone! Begone dot!

Answer (score 0):

The javascript to "flip" the content on larger screens is adding `direction: rtl;` this is a poor use of that attribute since it's trying to actually make it so you *Read Right to Left* and therefore putting the punctuation at the semantic "end of the line".

It should be:

```
.timeline-block-left {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
}
```

And you'll need to move the blue circle to the line manually.

Answer (score 0):

Dot appears due to `direction: rtl;` property of your `p` - you should normally use `rtl` only for texts in a language that is written right to left, and only for them.

There's couple of ways to deal with that:

### Using `text-align`

Use `text-align` property to align your paragraph instead of relying on `direction` property.

Add this code to your css, and dot will show on the right side.

```
.timeline-block-left .timeline-content p {
  text-align: right;
  direction: ltr;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .timeline-block-left .timeline-content p {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: #F1F2F6;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #777
}

h1 span {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #CCD1D9;
  z-index: 1
}

.timeline-block {
  width: -webkit-calc(50% + 8px);
  width: -moz-calc(50% + 8px);
  width: calc(50% + 8px);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  clear: both;
}

.timeline-block-right {
  float: right;
}

.timeline-block-left {
  float: left;
  direction: rtl;
}

.marker {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #F5F7FA;
  background: #4FC1E9;
  margin-top: 10px;
  z-index: 9999
}

.timeline-content {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: #666
}

.timeline-content h3 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500
}

.timeline-content span {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #a4a4a4;
}

.timeline-content p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  color: #888;
}

.timeline-block-left .timeline-content p {
  text-align: right;
  direction: ltr;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container:before {
    left: 8px;
    width: 2px;
  }
  .timeline-block {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .timeline-block-right {
    float: none;
  }
  .timeline-block-left {
    float: none;
    direction: ltr;
  }
  .timeline-block-left .timeline-content p {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Pure Css responsive <span>timeline</span></h1>

<div class="container">

  <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h3>First Year</h3>
      <span>Some work experience</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-left">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h3>Seconed Year</h3>
      <span>Some work experience</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h3>Third Year</h3>
      <span>Some work experience</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-left">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h3>Fourth Year</h3>
      <span>Some work experience</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h3>Fifth Year</h3>
      <span>Some work experience</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Using `&lrm;` character

You can use `&lrm;` ([Left-to-right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark)) in right-to-left text to force your punctuation to show on the right side.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: #F1F2F6;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #777
}

h1 span {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #CCD1D9;
  z-index: 1
}

.timeline-block {
  width: -webkit-calc(50% + 8px);
  width: -moz-calc(50% + 8px);
  width: calc(50% + 8px);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  clear: both;
}

.timeline-block-right {
  float: right;
}

.timeline-block-left {
  float: left;
  direction: rtl
}

.marker {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #F5F7FA;
  background: #4FC1E9;
  margin-top: 10px;
  z-index: 9999
}

.timeline-content {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: #666
}

.timeline-content h3 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500
}

.timeline-content span {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #a4a4a4;
}

.timeline-content p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  color: #888;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container:before {
    left: 8px;
    width: 2px;
  }
  .timeline-block {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .timeline-block-right {
    float: none;
  }
  .timeline-block-left {
    float: none;
    direction: ltr;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Pure Css responsive <span>timeline</span></h1>

<div class="container">

  <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h3>First Year</h3>
      <span>Some work experience</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-left">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h3>Seconed Year</h3>
      <span>Some work experience</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.&lrm;</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h3>Third Year</h3>
      <span>Some work experience</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-left">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h3>Fourth Year</h3>
      <span>Some work experience</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.&lrm;</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
    <div class="marker"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <h3>Fifth Year</h3>
      <span>Some work experience</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is what I got so far. https://jsfiddle.net/dcannon96/3jes2y7z/ I was able to get rid of the period thanks to Flavio Caruso. Now I am not sure what to do with .timeline-content p?

Comment: Is there another alternative to fixing the dot to be put back on the timeline instead of hanging on the left side of the text? It looks fine when it in responsive because the dot is on the line already.

Comment: Here is what I got so far. https://jsfiddle.net/dcannon96/y3cbk86s/2/ Now what can I do to get the blue dot to line up in the middle timeline line?

Comment: Also I noticed the left column's paragraph is not lined up perfectly like the paragraph in the right column. How do I fix that?